# What are these 3 thin lines draining into my sump well?

Tags: basement

There are 3 thin lines draining constantly into my sump well.  The lines are coming through the concrete to the best of my knowledge because i can't trace them on the walls or ceiling.  I am having a constant pumping through the line in the upper left of the well, every 30 seconds of a fair amount of water, causing my sump pump to run every 20 minutes.  This is creating an issue with drainage in my yard.  I'm assuming that the french drain installed doesn't have anything to do with these lines, but could they be from the wall mounted inline water heater?  Or even the refrigerator line?   I also have a water treatment system, but i have bypassed this to remove it from the equation.    Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated as i have been dealing with this issue for quite some time.[image]

Comment: How many A/C units do you have? Also, better a wet yard then a flooded basement.

Comment: There's only 1 ac unit, and i haven't had it on this year.  This problem persisted through out the winter.  Definately better a wet backyard, but i am having complaints from a neighbor because the water is flooding into their yard. And i already burnt up a sump pump last year, and am concerned about doing the same this year.

Comment: What type of furnace do you have? Do you have a whole house humidifier? Do you have a dehumidifier? Are you discharging the water you're pumping out, far enough away from the foundation (and not uphill)? Do you have a reverse osmosis system?

Comment: Dehumidifier is another possibility.  Condensing boiler might be another though mine drains into the plumbing via a transfer pump.  What else...

Comment: The furnace does have one of the lines running into the sump, but it's not the one in question.  I do not have a whole home dehumidifier.  The thing that puzzles me is how the small tubing is coming through the concrete.  Seems to me that would be suggesting it was something installed early on in the building of the home.  I'm pretty sure the larger holes in the well are the french drain.  The well is not seeming to connect to the sump.  I was pumping downhill so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions for investigation:

(1) Temporarily attach it to a piece of transparent tubing held vertically above the sump, to see how high the water rises. This will give you a clue to the location of the source.

(2) Force high pressure air into it and walk around listening for a hissing noise.

(3) Stop it up and see what floods or overflows.  Be prepared with mops, bucket, shop-vac, etc.

(4) Inject a harmless dye or other tracer under pressure and see what turns colors.  Green is best for deniability if it turns out the source is not on your property.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a tone of things that use water and see if it fills up maybe somebody before used the plumbing as a sewage sump pump and if the house had a septic before maybe thats why it flood the yard because they are usually hooked up to that

Comment: Welcome. Your answer would be easier to understand if you punctuated your sentences properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).